# Sylius - [Admin] How to edit the indexAction grid query

Tags: php, symfony4, sylius

I'm just trying to edit the **indexAction** in **product** controller doing some data filtering. what I did was I added new column as **branch_code** and in product table and the user table , when each user login to the system they show the product list according to the their **branch_code**

I'm just trying to change query in resources (Please refer the attachment). and I count catch it,[image]

What I need is, I want to add a `WHERE` condition to this query,

Can you please guide me solve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [extend the product repository](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/repository.html) and extend the `createListQueryBuilder` method to add your custom logic.
If that is not enough, then you can create a new method, then [override the admin product grid](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/grid.html) and change the [repository method](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/product.yml#L9).

Comment: yes I did it and I created a new method and it works,  I want a small help . do you have any idea how to pass the logged user for that grid arguments?

Comment: You can use the expression language and the customer context to pass the customer to the repository method, then inside of it get it's user if there's one: "expr:service('sylius.context.customer').getCustomer()"`
If the customer is not registered and logged in, the `$customer->getUser()` will return null.

Comment: I'm using the admin panel so those method return me the null as you said, what I need to do is get the admin_user (logged user). can you please guide me on it

Comment: `"expr:service('security.token_storage').getToken().getUser()"`