# Sylius [Admin] How to get logged user details directly inside the Repository function

Tags: php, symfony4, sylius

I need to get the logged user details inside of the Repository function (**createListQueryBuilder**) with out passing the user details from the controller.

This is how my **Repository** looks like.

```
class ProductRepository extends BaseProductRepository
{
   public function createListQueryBuilder(string $locale, $taxonId = null): QueryBuilder
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->addSelect('translation')
            ->innerJoin('o.translations', 'translation', 'WITH', 'translation.locale = :locale')
            ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
        ;

        if (null !== $taxonId) {
            $queryBuilder
                ->innerJoin('o.productTaxons', 'productTaxon')
                ->andWhere('productTaxon.taxon = :taxonId')
                ->setParameter('taxonId', $taxonId)
            ;
        }

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553146/sylius-admin-how-to-edit-the-indexaction-grid-query/62553695?noredirect=1#comment110632022_62553695).

For more context, this method is going to be used in a [Sylius Grid configuration](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusGridBundle/blob/master/docs/configuration.md), which supports [Symfony's Expression Language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) for repository method arguments, when Doctrine ORM (`doctrine/orm`) is used as driver.